# NAND Flash reader using FTDI

Tags: ftdi

I'm trying to read data off a Hynix NAND Flash chip.

Ive soldered the NAND Flash onto a break out board and connected it to my FT2232H FTDI.

I'm using the following software to read the NAND Flash:
https://github.com/ohjeongwook/DumpFlash

However, I get the following output when I run it:

```
C:\NAND>python DumpFlash.py -i
Name:           NAND 128MiB 3,3V 8-bit
ID:             0xf1
Page size:      0x0
OOB size:       0x0
Page count:     0x0
Size:           0x80
Erase size:     0x0
Options:        1
Address cycle:  4
Manufacturer:   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DumpFlash.py", line 93, in <module>
    flash_util.io.DumpInfo()
  File "C:\NAND\FlashDevice.py", line 314, in DumpInfo
    print 'Manufacturer:\t',self.Manufacturer
AttributeError: NandIO instance has no attribute 'Manufacturer'

C:\NAND>
```

I have double checked my wiring and I believe it's all correct.

Would anyone have any advice to explain why it's not being recognized? Have I busted the NAND Flash?

Comment: Please post a link to the Hynix NAND part, or its data sheet.

Comment: Sorry, it is: http://natisbad.org/NAS/refs/Hynix_NAND_128Mo_H27U1G8F2BT.pdf

Answer (score 5):

The code you are using, specifically `FlashDevice.py` attempts to match a variety of manufacturer IDs.

```
    if id[0]==0x98:
        self.Manufacturer="Toshiba";
    if id[0]==0xec:
        self.Manufacturer="Samsung";
    if id[0]==0x04:
        self.Manufacturer="Fujitsu";
    if id[0]==0x8f:
        self.Manufacturer="National Semiconductors";
    if id[0]==0x07:
        self.Manufacturer="Renesas";
    if id[0]==0x20:
        self.Manufacturer="ST Micro";
    if id[0]==0xad:
        self.Manufacturer="Hynix";
    if id[0]==0x2c:
        self.Manufacturer="Micron";
    if id[0]==0x01:
        self.Manufacturer="AMD";
    if id[0]==0xc2:
        self.Manufacturer="Macronix";
```

Likely yours is not being matched either because it is misread, or unknown, and this leaves the field undefined, causing the error you see.  I would suggest you try preceding these "if" statement with a default, ie:

```
    self.Manufacturer="Unrecognized";
    if id[0]==0x98:
        self.Manufacturer="Toshiba";
```

Going a step further you could try something like this (completely untested):

```
    self.Manufacturer=hex(id[0])+" is unrecognized";
    if id[0]==0x98:
        self.Manufacturer="Toshiba";
```

According to your data sheet, the code for your chip *should be* `0xad` which is in the list, so likely these changes won't actually get things working, but will get you past that particular program crash and so perhaps allow you to learn more.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I ended up adding a default if statement, which resulted in this:


!!! Manufacturer was not found

id[0]=0x4f, id[1]=0x4e, id[2]=0x46, id[3]=49

Comment: That is "ONFI" which the code seems to look for.  Have a look at the code and the data sheet and figure out how it is supposed to work, and then you may be able to guess how it failed (for example, perhaps it somehow got a stale result from a previous operation?)

Comment: I realised it was "ONFI" soon after too, it doesn't detect "ONFI" properly. When I change the code to force it to go to "ONFI" mode the same thing as before occurs...

Comment: Does this mean my wiring is correct and the NAND isn't busted? Meaning the software is the problem here?

Comment: I'd suggest you make it log all read and write operations, and compare them against data sheet expectations.  Either the chip doesn't behave as expected, the USB latency introduces some oddity, or there's something subtly wrong with your wiring (for example, I had an SPI flash device wire-wrapped to an eval board that would work wonderfully right up until I tried to write to it its memory cells - at which point the lack of a ground connection would finally cause a problem)